# Authentication and Authorization with AWS API Gateway from MobileApp (Android + IOS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, authorization, mobile-application

User can sign in using any of the following from the Mobile App:

a. Facebook ID

b. Google Id

c. Apple Id (for IOS)

d. Mobile No

e. Email Id

Now, if the user tries to sign in using any of the Social Media Login, the information will be checked back in the database (DynamoDB) before allowing the user further accessing the other microservices.

if the user tries to login using mobile no or email, then the information will be checked back in the database (DynamoDB), and if exists, then it is followed by a OTP for verification.

How to design a robust authentication and authorization structure which may help with the following:

a. Security (must)

b. Performance (must)

c. Token may contain necessary information like userid, name etc, if possible

d. Invalidate, if possible

Possible Tech Stack : Mobile Apps -> API Gateway -> Lambda -> DynamoDB

Comment: I think this might work: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-use-lambda-authorizer.html.

Comment: You may want to use AWS Cognito. See the link: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/integrating-amazon-cognito-user-pools-with-api-gateway/